# How can i redirect command output in OS X to both console and file at the same time

Tags: macos, bash, terminal

I need to basically see the output of a command which are logs that could run into 1000+ lines while at the same time send it to a file. please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `tee` command:

```
mycommand | tee filename.txt
```

Will run `mycommand` saving standard output to `filename.txt` while also displaying it on the terminal.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of trying to duplicate the output (I/O is expensive!), how about writing to the file and opening a separate terminal and using `tail -f <file>.log` at the same time?